# What are the Jena OWL Reasoners Limitations?

Tags: jena, semantic-web, owl, reasoning

I have been making some tests using Jena OWL Reasoner, but I don´t understand some results obtained, for example, if I have the following KB:

```
Class A 
Class B
Class C rdfs:subClassOf A
A owl:disjointWith B
```

...and if I ask `"C owl:disjointWith B"`? to the inference model, the answer sould be `"yes"`, but the Jena OWL Reasoner answer is NO...I check this using...

```
if (infmodel.contains(A, OWL.disjointWith, C)) {
... 
}
....
```

So, is there some limitations to make inferences with this reasoner?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query contains `A owl:disjointWith C`, which cannot be inferred from your ontology. Are you sure it's the correct query?

Comment: Ignazio, thanks for your help. There was an error in the previous message. I want to check:  if (infmodel.contains(B, OWL.disjointWith, C)) (or C, OWL.disjointWith, B), but the answer is 'NO', when 'Yes' would be expected....

Comment: Try the reverse: b disjoint c or c disjoint b. In owl these are equivalent but in rdf the triples are distinct

Comment: I tried both, "b disjoint c" and "c disjoint b",  without success , I guess it is due to Jena incomplete implementation of the OWL/Lite subset of the OWL/Full language...but I'm not sure....